# curl Based Authentication on cakephp application

Tags: cakephp, curl

I have developed one application using cakephp , now i want to authenticate to my application by using call from remote server

Currently i have set up simple auth based authentication mechanism on my application , but i guess by using that I won't be able to perform my task , so i am now using security component to perform simple http based authentication, but still i am not able to perform curl based authentication

Can anyone tell me how to do this? Is curl based authenticaion on cakephp possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.

Basic authentication:

```
curl --user username:password http://www.mysite.com
```

Cookie based authentication:

```
curl -Lc 'cookiefile.txt' -d 'user=username&pass=password' http://www.mysite.com
```

The details depend on how your security scheme is implemented.